# Generate a random Alphanumeric String without some characters

Tags: java, random, alphanumeric

I want to generate a random Alphanumeric String. I want to exlude some characters from my string

> l, i, o and the number 0

For the moment i have this code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
...
numberFile = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric( 5 );
```

Comment: How `myCode.substring` is related to your problem?

Comment: @talex sorry is a mistake

Comment: What is `RandomStringUtils`? I suppose it is from apache commons. If so there no function you need in this library.

Comment: @talex `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(int count)` no there function in this library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `RandomStringUtils` you might aswell use the designated `RandomStringUtils#random` method for that.

```
public static String random(int count,
                            int start,
                            int end,
                            boolean letters,
                            boolean numbers,
                            char... chars)
```

Parameters:
count - the length of random string to create
start - the position in set of chars to start at
end - the position in set of chars to end before
letters - only allow letters?
numbers - only allow numbers?
chars - the set of chars to choose randoms from. If null, then it will use the set of all chars.

See the docs [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html).

Comment: it's possible to use a `Regex` 

`String test;
do {
    test= randomAlphanumeric(10);
} while (!test.matches(REGEX ???); `

Comment: @Mercer Why would you use a regex if there is the exact method available you want to use?

Answer (score 4):

Construct an array with the element from which your string want to be built upon.

Let's say C=`{a,b,c,d....,1,2,3..}` has size `n`

Generate `n` random numbers in the range `[0,n-1]`, for example `D={3,5,1,0,2..}`.
Now if you build a string `s` from `D` as follows:`s[i] = C[D[i]]` what you get is a random string from a set of chars defined in `C`, which a guess is exactly what you want.

You can easily make `C` such that it does not contain the set of characters you don't want to appear in your random `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Turning Davide Spataro's answer into code without using any 3rd party library could look like this:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "123456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";

public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
    Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    int alphabetLength = ALPHABET.length();
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        chars[i] = ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(alphabetLength));
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

Or alternatively a Java 8 Stream based approach:

```
public static String generateRandomStringJava8(int length) {
    return IntStream.range(0, length)
            .map(i -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(ALPHABET.length()))
            .mapToObj(i -> ALPHABET.substring(i, i + 1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Both methods generate `String`s of given `length` by picking `length` random characters from the static `ALPHABET`.